# Avoid stop docker container if script inside to raises error

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to avoid failure cascade of script inside docker, it fails on the command `( echo time fmriprep)`, and exits from docker container, i want it ignore the error on this command and to be continued with `input=/tmp/preproc/fmriprep && \`. Here is the script:

```
if [ ! -f "/input/preproc/fmriprep/sub-"${subject_id}".html" ]
    then
    ( echo `time fmriprep /input/BIDS /tmp/preproc participant --skip-bids-validation --fs-license-file /opt/freesurfer/license.txt --ignore fieldmaps --fs-no-reconall --use-aroma --force-bbr --participant_label $subject_id -w /tmp/preproc || true` ) && \
    cp -r /tmp/preproc /input &
else
        mkdir -p /tmp/preproc/fmriprep
        cp -r /input/preproc/fmriprep/sub-${subject_id}/ /tmp/preproc/fmriprep
fi && \
    input=/tmp/preproc/fmriprep && \
```

I tried to added `|| true`, but it didn't helped

Comment: Why is this specific to docker? Did you test the script outside of Docker? And is the script really run by bash (and not by whatever `sh` is in the container...)

Comment: it is wrapped inside docker because a lot of requirements should be installed in the environment. particularly fmriprep

Comment: Yes but you can test the script outside of docker (replace fmiprep by `/bin/false` or `/bin/true`). And you can also run it manually in the container. It is also unclear which command is failing.

Comment: If it exits from the docker container, the fail also causes the script to exit, for whatever reason. Is there a `trap` command somewhere in the script, or is what you've shown the complete script?

Comment: @dirkt it is not the full scirpt, i have `wait jobs -p && echo __ok__ || echo __err__` at the end if fi, it seems that `( echo time fmriprep /input/BIDS /tmp/preproc participant --skip-bids-validation --fs-license-file /opt/freesurfer/license.txt --ignore fieldmaps --fs-no-reconall --use-aroma --force-bbr --participant_label $subject_id -w /tmp/preproc || true ) && \
    cp -r /tmp/preproc /input || true` worked for this